# How to fetch script result in to a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to this huge programming world and I'm currently learning python. I recently created a script that queries a database and processed the received data. I'm trying to find a way to send email with the result of this script from the script itself. I have no doubt how to use the email module, but I have no idea how to get the entire result of the script and put it in the body of the email. Would anyone know how to do it? I've already spent a few hours searching and unfortunately the only way I found was to save .txt files. However I would not like to populate the server with files.

My code:

```
import psycopg2 ### postgres connect module
from psycopg2 import Error

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                              password="password",
                              host="host",
                              port="port",
                              database="database")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''select data to retrieve as tuples.''')
     bases = cursor.fetchall()
    print('=-'*5,'\033[31mData from query\033[0m','=-'*5)
    for row in bases:
        print('Data1 =', row[0],'|','Data2 =', row[1])

except (Exception, Error) as error:
    print("Conection with database Error", error)
```

Basically the repetition loop brings me a list of data treated in two columns in which I need to send that list in the body of an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the "huge" programming world :)

Before I start, I want to recommend you to use the code snippets in the stackoverflow editor to highlight your code, it makes things easier to read.

You say you want to store the output of a script into a variable. In python, if you're running code, you usually want to prevent running scripts inside of scripts, as a script is meant to run standalone (and not rely on others). I recommend you rewrite the code you want to store as a python [function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp), i.e.

```py
def get_data_as_strings():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                                  password="password",
                                  host="host",
                                  port="port",
                                  database="database")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''select data to retrieve as tuples.''')
    bases = cursor.fetchall()
    #  Return the data as a string for each row (as you did before).
    return [f'Data1 = {row[0]} | Data2 = {row[1]}' for row in bases]

def send_email():
    try:
        # Get the data as a list of strings
        data = get_data_as_strings()
        # Concatenate all data with newlines in between
        data_str = data.join('\n')
        # Not sure which email module you use, but send the message here
        email_module.send(data_str)  
    except (Exception, Error) as error:
        print("Conection with database Error", error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_email()
```

Of course you'd want it to be more sophisticated, this is just exemplary and you mention you've got the email logic in place. This way, even if you store the `get_data_as_strings` function in another file, you will be able to [import](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) it and call if from a python script.

I hope this helps, let me know if anything is still unclear/incomplete.

Comment: Thx for you answer, im editing post right now with a sample of the code.

Comment: @FilipeEiti if this answered your question, please mark it as answered. It helps both me and any future viewers of this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting.

```
message = f'{first_variable} some text between. {second_variable} some text between. {third_variable}'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you wanna merge your variables with the message string you can do this :

var1 = "client last name"
var2 = "client first name"

message = "static string here {} static again {}".format(var1, var2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I rephrased my question with an example on top of what I am proposing, if you can review I thank you thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:
(There are no print results. You should save the data you print in a variable if you need it later)

```
# save what you want to print in a variable first

first_string = "Something here"
second_string = "More data here"
third_string = "and the last one here"

print(first_string)
print(second_string)
print(third_string)

# now you can put it in your message

message = first_string + ", " + second_string + ", " + third_string
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I rephrased my question with an example on top of what I am proposing, if you can review I thank you thank you.

Comment: Review my other answer two below which should help you make an email message with the data you print in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send an email with the exact same thing you print in the console. Is that right? If so, then this will help (this is your for loop)

```
# idealy you want this in the same for loop that you run for printing it out in the console.
# \n is a line break so "123\n456" is the same as the following:

# 123
# 456


message = 'This is your report:\n'
for row in bases:
    print('Data1 =', row[0],'|','Data2 =', row[1])
    message = message + 'Data1 is ' + row[0] + ' and Data2 is ' + row[1] + '\n'
```

Is this what you want to do? (You can mark it as an answer if it is or let me know if it isn't and you need any further help :)